# VB Send Rcon commands and get response back. (CS:GO Servers)

Tags: vb.net, packets

I am trying to make a connection with a CS:GO game server using Rcon.

all I would like to do is send the "status" command to get player list for now, once I get that sent, I can probably figure out how to send other commands.

Edit: Like this.

SendCommand(IP,Port,Command) - Idk if it could be done like this.

Im not sure if I can just send the command "rcon_password 1234" then "rcon status"

It sounds simple to me, until I google it and find out how others have done it for Quake and CoD...

I don't know where to start, any help is appreciated.

Found this, Not sure how or what to do with it... I don't know much about network related programming with packets and such... :S

```
 Private Function RCON_Command(ByVal Command As String, ByVal ServerData As Integer) As Byte()
 Dim Packet As Byte() = New Byte(CByte((13 + Command.Length))) {}
 Packet(0) = Command.Length + 9       'Packet Size (Integer)
 Packet(4) = 0                        'Request Id (Integer)
 Packet(8) = ServerData               'SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND / SERVERDATA_AUTH (Integer)
 For X As Integer = 0 To Command.Length - 1
     Packet(12 + X) = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Command(X))(0)
 Next
 Return Packet
```

End Function

Comment: `I don't know where to start` -- `I don't know much about network related programming with packets and such` - Then Stack Overflow is not the forum for you. We're here to help you with a **specific programming related problem**, not write the code for you.

Comment: There's going to be a lot of coding behind what you want to achieve. Most RCON clients not only send data, but also receive it in order to know the state of the game (i.e. map, player count, etc.) and to receive the server log and chat. In other words you must know much about network related programming in order to complete such a task. -- CS:GO, like many others, uses the [_**Source RCON Protocol**_](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol) for its RCON communication. You can use the article I just linked you to as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I understand that this is not a forum to write code for me, I was more or less just looking to see if there is a way for me to start, I have seen what you have linked me before, I just needed help trying to figure out how that ties into the code I posted, I have also looked up Winsock, is that a viable option for this? I have seen that some people say its "dated" Thanks again for the response.

Comment: Maybe I can use something from here: https://www.vb-paradise.de/index.php/Thread/108983-CS-GO-Rcon-Tool-mit-Winsock-dotNet-beendet-sich/

Comment: I have no idea if you can use Winsock... Either way I'd use the built-in TcpClient instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way around this, I have found a project that will do what I need, All I have to do is work it into my project.

I just edited it to send the servers response to a file and have my main project read it.

ex: shell("/c file.exe IP PORT PASSWORD CMD")

If anyone wants to see:
https://github.com/aiusepsi/SourceRcon